# How does profvis work in R?

Tags: r, profiling

After updating Rstudio, there is a new button called "Profile" in the menu. After reading some information in the website of Rprofvis, it turns out "profile" can calculate the code running speed. However, suppose I have following Rcode

```
library(nycflights13)
head(flights)
dim(flights)
library(dplyr)

filter(flights,month == 1 & day == 1)
flights[flights$month == 1 && flights$day == 1,]
dplyr::distinct(flights,day,month)
```

Then I started profiling all the code above but it seems R didn't respond to it and never gave me a result. But if I only selected

```
 dplyr::distinct(flights,day,month)
```

Then clicked "profile select lines". It did give me what I expected. So is there any explanation for this phenomenon?

Comment: This seems pretty general. maybe [here](https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/rstudio.html) is a good starting place.

Comment: I have read this page but it couldn't help me out. As my code above, if I get my cursor before `library(nycflights13)`, it wouldn't give me any output, the only thing I can do is to stop profiling